Getting error "HTTP/1.1 431 Request Header Fields Too Large" in Apache Jmeter
I have an API in Jmeter in which I am passing a token(extracted from previous API) and I am getting an error: HTTP/1.1 431 Request Header Fields Too Large.
To pass headers I am using HHTP Header Manger Jmeter Header Manager
This API however works fine from Postman on same machine.
Couldn't find any specific solution to my problem
Screen-shots:
Jmeter Error
Jmeter Request
Postman Authorization
Postman Headers

Could you please share screenshots of the Postman setup, including the headers, input body, output body, and tests scripts? This will help us better understand and address your issue.

Hello @BenchVue I have added the required screen-shots in my question. Please let me know if any other info is required

It seems JMeter's header size is not enough for your API. #1 try find the header size by curl command, cur commend can export from Postman, -I or --head option is curl get header size.  curl -I [URL] #2 Try upgrading JMeter latest version 5.6.3, #3 still not fix , I have no idea.

From Apache documentation, the header size is 8K.

The error is self-explanatory, as per Request Header Fields Too Large article:

The HTTP 431 Request Header Fields Too Large response status code indicates that the server refuses to process the request because the request's HTTP headers are too long. The request may be resubmitted after reducing the size of the request headers.
431 can be used when the total size of request headers is too large, or when a single header field is too large. To help those running into this error, indicate which of the two is the problem in the response body — ideally, also include which headers are too large. This lets users attempt to fix the problem, such as by clearing their cookies.

Try use Debug Sampler to see your access_token_metadata header value, it might be the case your correlation fails somehow and pulls some extra data

In general if you can successfully execute your request with Postman you should be able to record it using JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder, you will need to:

Configure Postman to use JMeter as the proxy


Import JMeter's certificate into Postman



More information: How to Convert Your Postman API Tests to JMeter for Scaling
